# Order column sums by highest value

Tags: php, pdo

I need to sum columns and sort them highest to lowest.

This is what I've tried!

```
$sth = $db->prepare("SELECT sum(A), sum(S), sum(D), sum(F) FROM XXX order by A, S, D, F DESC");
$sth->execute();

$result = $sth->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

This is what the output looks like:

```
Array ( [sum(A)] => 38 [sum(S)] => 194 [sum(D)] => 40 [sum(F)] => 164 )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not just use `rsort()`, in php when the results are returned??

`sort()` will to lowest to highest, `rsort()` will do highest to lowest

```
rsort($result);
print_r($result);
```

Or to keep the associative features of your array, use `asort()` (low->high), or `arsort()`;
(high->low)

```
arsort($result);
print_r($result);
```

Comment: I need the array to be associative with Name->Value

Comment: Beautiful, that did the trick, will mark it as answer in 2 minutes :)

Comment: Is it possible to "save it" in another variable like: $sortedDESC = arsort($result)?

Comment: Yes but you cant do it like you posted above.... because arsort() just returns a bool....so you have to assign to a new variable first, before sorting, then sort.  Like $sortedArray = $result; arsort($sortedArray);

Comment: I would vote you up aswell but my rep isn't high enough but a big thank you!

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT sum(A), sum(S), sum(D), sum(F) FROM XXX order by S DESC, A DESC, D DESC, F DESC
```

Basically you have to add the `DESC` to each column you want sorted in descending order.
The default being ASCending order.

Answer (score 0):

Copy and paste this code and you can figure it out:

```
$sth = array(

'sumA' => 38,
'sumB' => 194,
'sumC' => 40,
'sumD' => 164

);

arsort($sth);

foreach($sth as $element => $num){
    echo $element . $num . '</br>';
}
```